# Visual Studio Team Services creates commit on pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have three branches `master`, `dev` and `feature1` (gitflow process). `dev` and `master` have branch policies applied (minimum of 2 reviews) so cannot be committed to directly or merged to. Standard setup right? I make some commits to the `feature1` branch. I create and complete a pull request to get the commits from `feature1` into `dev`. I then create and complete a pull request to get the changes from `dev` into `master`. VSTS now tells me that `dev` is behind `master`. I can't merge `master` into `dev` due to the policies.

This is the state of my branchesafter four pull requests from `dev` into `master`.

[image: dev is four behind master]

[image: the four pull requests]

What can I do?

As suggested by Tim Biegeleisen, I have attempted to merge `dev` into `master` but am unable to do so due to the branch policies.

Merge `dev` into `master`

[image]

Commits are ready to be pushed to `dev`

[image]

Sync fails due to policies

[image]

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected dev -> dev (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)

Comment: Shouldn't you review whether `dev` is now in a good state as well?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what do you mean by "good state"?

Comment: You asked "what can I do", but you didn't really explain what you _wanted_ to do.  Do you really need `dev` and `master` to point to the same commit?
 Why?

Comment: You merged changes into the branch, it looks like your review process requires you to verify that those changes are safe to merge into master. I realize you've already reviewed them going from the feature branch to dev, but the change to dev was integrated with other changes done on dev, shouldn't you review that integration before you merge it into master?

Comment: @KevinBrydon can you provide the commit history graph (in local git repo, execute the two commands: `git fetch` and `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`, and then show the output graph from the last command)? And how did you complete the PR for merging `dev` into `master`, by default merge strategy or squash merge strategy?

Comment: @EdwardThomson what i want to see is dev being 0 behind and 0 ahead of master when a pull request is completed from dev into master. this makes it easy to see that they have the same code. in a few months time i'll have dev hundreds of commits behind master, this doesn't seem right.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the changes from dev into master are reviewed before being merged

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you described struck me as anything out of the ordinary.  You could easily end up in this situation if, for example, others had made some commits to `master` since the last time `dev` had synched with that branch.

The two typical ways to resolve this are merging and rebasing.  Let's consider merging, because it is probably the strategy you are already using, and it is more succinct to describe.  You could resolve this situation by first merging `master` into your `dev` branch.  Then, open a pull request back into `master` from `dev`, if one does not already remain open.  Have your reviewers sign off on it, and then the pull request should go through.

The key step here is merging `master` into your `dev` branch.  After this operation, Git should not longer be telling you that `dev` is behind `master`.

A side note: Technically speaking, `master` itself was also behind `dev`.  Actually, both branches were mutually behind the other party, because each has new commits since the last time they both synched.

Comment: I am unable to merge `master` into `dev` (which would solve the problem) due to the policies. The problem seems to be that the pullr equest creates a new commit in master. This seems different to other systems I've used such as bitbucket and github.

Comment: @KevinBrydon I doubt this; then what purpose does the pull request serve?
  If you can't merge `master` into `dev`, could you instead _rebase_ `dev` on `master` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the `master` to `dev` merge process. Just to confirm, I'm the only one at the moment who is commiting to these branches. the only code going into `dev` is from pull requests from `feature` branches. The only code going into `master` is pull requests from `dev`.

Comment: Sure, but branch policies prevent him from pushing a merge _or_ a rebase.  If your integration point is through pull requests, `dev` and `master` _cannot_ be identical, due to the commit created by VSTS when the pull request is merged.

Comment: @EdwardThomson is it only vsts that creates this additional commit when the pull request is merged? i don't remember it being created when using bitbucket or git. but maybe i'm mistaken?

Comment: @KevinBrydon  Regarding VSTS pull request, it will create a new commit, but the dev should just have 1 behind of master branch if the workflow is feature=>dev=>master. You can provide the history of these branches (screenshot) here.